# Getting Null pointer Exception while passing object from one fragment to another android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I am passing an object from one fragment to another but object is getting null while receiving.

**sending code**

```
   Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); 
CustomerInformationFragment fragment = new CustomerInformationFragment(); 
FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
bundle.putSerializable("Object", customer); 
Log.d("Kapil", "setData: " + customer.getClass().getSimpleName()); 
ft.commit(); 
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

**receiving a code**

```
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); 
Customer = (Customer) getArguments() .getSerializable("Object"); 
Log.d("Kapil", "onCreateView: " + customer.getFirstName());
```

**and I'm getting an error as**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.Serializable android.os.Bundle.getSerializable(java.lang.String)' 
on a null object reference at 
com.whattebiryani.Fragments.CustomerAddressFragment.onCreateView(CustomerAddressFragment.java:44) 
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2354) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1419) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1740) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1809) 
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:799) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2580) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2367) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2322) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2199) 
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:651) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:145)
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to set the arguments for your fragment and after that you have to commit the transaction:

```
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
ft.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Set arguments before committing the transaction.

```
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
ft.commit();
```